# Can I put ST-MRAM into a regular motherboard designed for DDR 3?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3

It says [here](http://www.everspin.com/products/second-generation-st-mram.html) that ST-MRAM is compatible with DDR 3. Does that mean I can put ST-MRAM into a regular motherboard that is designed for DDR 3?

Also, MRAM uses a lot less power than DDR 3. So if I can put ST-MRAM into a regular motherboard what will the MRAM do with all the extra power the motherboard is giving it?

And finally, will the processor be refreshing my MRAM that doesn't have to be refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they say it's DDR3, then yes, you can plug it into a DDR3 slot and it should work.

(*should*. You're supposed to be able to plug PCIe 1x cards into PCIe 4x or 8x slots, but I have a card here that insists on making interrupt storms when I try it.)

The memory controller will be "going through the motions" of refresh cycles but the ST-MRAM won't be doing anything with them.

About the "power" part of the question - that isn't how electrical power works. As long as the voltage is compatible (and if they say it's DDR3-compatible, they should be), electrical loads use only as much power as they need.

This is why you can plug a laptop computer (which needs about 50 to 120 watts) or, for that matter, an LED nightlight (which needs a fraction of a watt) into an AC outlet that can provide in the range of 1500 to 2000 watts... depending on what country you're in and what kind of outlet it is. Or connect a tiny 12 volt "grain of wheat" incandescent light bulb (which pulls about 0.06 amps) directly to a car battery (which can provide hundreds of amps, at least for a short time) and the bulb just lights up like always.

*verb. sap.*: There are no purchasable DDR3 modules using this stuff yet; "raw" chips but they appear to be of very small capacity compared to ordinary DRAM. See for example [this list of products at one of their distributors](http://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?N=4292725692).

Comment: So then why are there motherboards made special for DDR 4?

Comment: Because DDR4 _isn't_ compatible with DDR3 or the others.

Comment: The last line of your answer is not true. Everspin has a list of distributors who carry their products (or some of their products).

Comment: The possessor is constantly reading bits from memory and rewriting them. So what do you mean by "going through the motions"?

Comment: Although memory refresh does involve reading and rewriting the bits, this is not done by the processor in the same manner as normal memory reads and writes. The data does not move over the bus to and from the CPU in a refresh. (There is nowhere near enough bandwidth on the DDR3 bus to read and write all of RAM within the milliseconds required to avoid decay.) The details have changed over the years but in even relatively recent systems, the most the controller does is "wave the baton," i.e. supply clock signals to the refresh circuits on the DIMMs.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_refresh

Comment: About the distributors: Ahha. Yes, they're selling chips. If you'll go to say mouser.com and search for Everspin, you'll find the chips for sale...but no DIMMs using the chips. And, I see why: their largest chip is just 16 Mbit - 2 Mbytes. This is tiny compared to modern ordinary RAM chips. Seems like they have not developed their tech to compete head-on with ordinary dynamic RAM. They're in a more specialized market niche. http://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=everspin+technologies

Comment: So will the memory actually be using the power required for a refresh?

Comment: @IsaacD. - Your question isn't clear.  You still also seem confused on how power works.

Comment: A huge amount of power is spent on refreshing DRAM. I'm asking whether or not the MRAM will be using this power i.e. I'm asking whether it will actually be refreshed even though it doesn't have to.

Comment: No, it will not be refreshed, or consume the power that would be used by refresh.

Comment: But I question whether "a huge amount of power" is spent on refresh. Example: My laptop runs for about three hours on battery. On standby - during which the memory is kept refreshed - it lasts for about two days. This implies that memory refresh takes about 3 hours/48 hours = about 0.06, i.e. about 6% of the total power used when the system is running. I wouldn't call that "huge".

Comment: According to [this,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistive_random-access_memory#Power_consumption) DRAM consumes 100 times more power than MRAM.

Comment: Ok. But according to the numbers I just mentioned, even if you replace the DRAM in that laptop with something that uses ZERO power you're not going to extend the runtime by more than about 6%.